# Unless in third conditional sentences

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, synonyms, conditional-perfect, unless

"Jane wouldn't have found a job unless she had gone to London" is a natural-sounding sentence and has two different meanings, depending on whether Jane really did move to London or not:

(1) "Jane wouldn´t have found a job if she hadn't moved to London" (i.e. She found a job because she moved to London)

(2) "Jane would only have found a job by moving to London" (i.e. she didn't move to London so she remained jobless)

On the other hand, "The situation would have deteriorated unless I had arrived" is not natural-sounding and can only mean:

(3) "The situation would have deteriorated if I had not arrived"" (i.e. I arrived so the situation didn't deteriorate")

My questions are these:

Is "unless" only correct in third conditionals where the sentence remains true whether the condition occured or not - i.e. when it stresses logical realtionship between condition and result rather than telling us the actual result?

Conversely, should we use "if ... not" instead of "unless" where we want to make the outcome clear?

Comment: Remember: “Third conditional” is not a term taught to native speakers, only to ELL students.  It’s not a very good one, either:  English has at least a dozen “conditionals”. This makes “third conditional” a facile over-simplification. I suppose you mean when the protasis uses the past perfect construction. Or something like that.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a special term for a construction that's ungrammatical. How many conditionals are there? Eight, like parts of speech? Seven, like gifts of the holy ghost?

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm a bit confused by your use of the phrase *a construction that's ungrammatical*. Could you elucidate, please?

Comment: @tchrist It's a sensible term to use on a site like this, because otherwise you're going to have to spend years explaining what kind of sentence you're talking about

Comment: No, it's precisely the wrong way to go about it. You should give examples of the phenomenon you're talking about instead of trying to describe it. People are generally not taught to think in terms of grammatical description, and if they are, they're not taught in any standard way. So people use whatever terminology they please, in the expectation that everyone will understand them. This is a false expectation. Nobody ever gets an answer until they provide ***Examples***.

Comment: We have P unless Q, which translates to if Q, then not P. P = "She wouldn't have found a job" and Q = "she had gone to London". The original sentence parses well with good grammar and unambiguous meaning, including being normally expressed in those terms. It means "She found a job because she went to London" except that it wouldn't have the emotional impact of the expressed statement. (That is to say, the conclusion isn't as expressive as the path.)

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't disagree about giving examples as well as descriptions. (But it isn't enough top say things like *when the protasis uses the past perfect construction*, because if there's not modal in the apodosis/consequent or whatever you will, then it won't read like a subjunctive/remote/backshifted conditional blah blah blah). What I really'd like to understand is what you mean by *a construction that's ungrammatical*? I find it a bit confusing ...

Comment: I still don't know what is meant by "third conditional", and I'm guessing that _The situation would have deteriorated unless I had arrived_ is an example of it. But it's ungrammatical, and it's hard to see how it can be an example of a real construction. Calling it a "third conditional" does not help.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree it's clunky and hard to make sense of, but - and maybe this is an across the pond thing - it sounds grammatical enough to me. The OP's first example does too. You can find subjunctive/remote conditionals with *unless* all over the pace: *It wouldn't have happened unless I'd wanted it to* etc etc. Language students are routinely taught the  - I agree completely fictitious - 3rd conditional. It's basically a 'remote' or 'subjunctive' conditional notionally about the past.

Comment: @Araucaria: I am grateful for the fact that I am neither responsible for nor cognizant of what "Language students are routinely taught" about English grammar. There's no first or second conditional in English, so why should there be a third? Tradition! (cue music).

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in 3rd conditional doesn't sound natural to my ear.To express the concept that moving to London was the condition sine-qua-non to get a job would be: *Jane would have found a job if she had moved to London*. (Unless is useless in your negative conditional) OR: *Jane would have never found a job if she hadn't moved to London...*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Susanna. Both examples are in the 3rd conditional, not just the one about Jane moving to London. Also, other native English speakers tell me that the Jane example _is_ natural-sounding (and we can find many similar examples by typing -"she wouldn't have * unless she had"- into Google). My question is why the second sentence sounds unnatural. Incidentally, the term 3rd conditional to which some people objected, is any sentence referring to an ‘unreal’ past in counterfactual conditions, including conditional clauses with if or unless. I could not find the tags for these.